# Read C# Textblock Text Property filled using Inlines

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, inlines

Let us say that I have an empty Textblock :

```
textblock1.Text = "";
```

Then I only put Inlines content in it with these two statements:

```
textblock1.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "A. ", Foreground = Brushes.Red });
textblock1.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = responses.Current.Value, Foreground = Brushes.Black});
```

The amazing stuff is that I can visualize the content properly in my window, however the Text property of the Textblock keeps being empty! This causes a problem because I need to pass the value of this Textblock to an other Textblock.

The other thing I really can't figure out is that when I call my function for second time, the textblock1.Text property is being updated properly ! It is updated properly for every call but the first ! I've spent hours on msdn but I'm really confused. Moreover, I can read that on the website :

> The Text property returns a value (the appended text of all Run elements in the InlineCollection). However, the returned value does not include any formatting that has been applied to the Run elements.

I have very carefully checked my code and debugged to see if there were any other place where I manipulate these property, but I haven't found one. If anyone has any idea, to me this thing is becoming senseless...

Comment: When and how in your code are you using the value of the Text property? Is it through a binding or direct access to the property?

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

I also use this later in my code to add the value of Textblock1 to an other Textblock
textBlock2.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = TextBlock11.Text + " ", FontSize = 25, Foreground = couleurSerie });
And that's it ! 
I do it by direct access in my code-behind

Comment: Are you doing this in the View's code-behind constructor? if so move it to the Loaded event of the Window and it should be fine even for the first time.

Comment: Thank you Viv, it works!! Actually I wasn't doing it in the constructor, but with a function that I called from the parent window, so I guess before the Loaded event was fired.
But why is that ? =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to elaborate on my comment to give some meaning,

From [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx)

> Loaded entails that the logical tree that an element is contained within is complete

which helps us since the binding here has a reference to the other `TextBlock` element. Bindings also depend on `DataContext` and few other factors relative to the specific `Binding` but in general they get evaluated after the UI Loads for good reason.

Hence setting the `Text` of the source `TextBlock` once the UI loads results in everything working fine since `Binding`'s are active at that point.