# Superscript in TextBlock WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, superscript

I have a `TextBlock` and the `Text` is read from a `.json` file. In this text there is some O(n^3/4) which I want to replace with the proper superscript version of it. Is there a way to do it, not in XAML?

Comment: I think you may have to process the entries into either rich text or possibly just directly into [`Inlines`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170006/read-c-sharp-textblock-text-property-filled-using-inlines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Typography.Variants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.typography.variants.aspx) allows you to specify text formatting as super/sub-script. The documentation shows how to achieve it with `Runs` in a `Paragraph` of a rich text box, but you can also do that in `Inlines` of a `TextBlock`.