# Text property of text box not set when text added using inlines

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textblock

I am trying to format parts of the text something like 'this is ***test***'. where parts of the string are bold and in italic. I get the string as a collection of words {word1, word2, word3......}

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=MyTextBlock}">
<TextBlock src:TextHelper.FormattedText="{Binding ListOfWords}" Name="MyTextBlock"/>
```

And in the helper i am parsing through the collection of words and i am setting the inline with the formatting which is working fine i.e. i see the correctly formatted text on the UI

```
textBlock.Inlines.Add(span);
```

But when the button is clicked the first time i don't get any value because the text property of the text block is empty.

I came across a similar question

[Read C# Textblock Text Property filled using Inlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170006/read-c-sharp-textblock-text-property-filled-using-inlines)

But I cannot use loaded method. Is there some way to get the value of text and pass to the command ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a reference as follows

```
 CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference MyTextBlock}}"
```

or (passing the whole TextBlock)

```
 CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyTextBlock}}"
```

In addition, you could also make the Command async and await a certain number of Task.Delay till the property gets filled.